# cannot run program with pointer and fstream in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, fstream

I can run my program in codeblock or visual studio 2015 but it doesn't work in visual studio 2017

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void replacechar(char *filenguon, char ktc, char ktm)
{
    fstream fs(filenguon, ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!fs)
        cout << "khong the tim thay" << endl;
    else
    {
        char ch;
        while (fs.get(ch))
        {
            if (ch == ktc)
            {
                int pos = fs.tellg();
                pos--;
                fs.seekp(pos);
                fs.put(ktm);
                fs.seekg(pos + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    replacechar("caua.txt", 'r', 'R');
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
  Error C2664   'void replacechar(char *,char,char)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'char *'   

    Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *" 

    Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'std::streamoff' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

I can run my program in codeblock or visual studio 2015 but it doesn't work in visual studio 2017

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? is there an error? is it the wrong result?

Comment: sorry. I just updated

Comment: You could improve the ease of understanding your question by translating everything to English. Also, try for more self-explanatory identifiers.

Comment: So when you write "run" you mean "build"? Because those are compiler errors. Changing that would also help reducing confusion.

Comment: `char *filenguon` ==> `const char *filenguon`, `int pos = fs.tellg();` ==> `auto pos = fs.tellg();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to pass a `const char*` (in your case the string literal `"caua.txt"` to a function accepting a non-const `char*`.

Change your signature to `void replacechar(const char *filenguon, char ktc, char ktm)`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
void replacechar(char *filenguon, char ktc, char ktm)
```

to

```
void replacechar(const char *filenguon, char ktc, char ktm)
```

The rules about *string literals* changed in C++11 (I think). They are const data and so any function parameter to which you pass a string literal should be declared with `const`.

And, as stated in the comments, change

```
int pos = fs.tellg();
```

to

```
auto pos = fs.tellg();
```

The return from `tellg` is not an `int`, by using `auto` you are asking the compiler to use the correct type, whatever that is.

Answer (score 2):

Two methods:
1.

```cpp
void replacechar(const char *filenguon, char ktc, char ktm)
{
    //TODO
}
```

  2.

```cpp
char str[]={"caua.txt";};
replacechar(str, 'r', 'R');
```

that should be work, "caua.txt" is `const char*`,it change to `char*` by copy one by one or `const_cast<char*>`